# Find all integers n such as $7^{n+1}-(n+1)7^n-1 = 0[4]$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Find all integers n such as $7^{n+1}-(n+1)7^n-1 = 0[4]$

we know that $ 7^2=1[4]$ But I don't know how to continue from here!
I tried the fact that

$7=7= -1 [4]$

$7^{2k} = 1 [4]$

$7^{2k+1} = -1 [4]$

The order is 2,

I get when considering $n=2k$ :

$-1-(n+1)×1-1 = -n-3 [4]$

The $ n $ keeps popping up !!
I cant get rid of it,
I need something $4k$  instead of $-n-3$

Plz help out !

Comment: if $n=2k$ then $n=0$ or $n=2$ so you just showed that even integers can't be a solution

Comment: Have you tried computing $7^{n+1}-(n+1)7^n-1 \bmod 4$ for $n=1$ to $10$?

Comment: Its 147 , not a solution !

Comment: What do you mean "147"?

Answer (score 1):

- If $n\equiv0\bmod2$,

then $7^{n+1}-(n+1)7^n-1\equiv 1-1-1=-1\equiv1\bmod2$,

so $7^{n+1}-(n+1)7^n-1\equiv 1$ or $3\bmod4$.

- If $n\equiv1\bmod4$,

then $7^{n+1}-(n+1)7^n-1\equiv(-1)^{n+1}-2(-1)^n-1\equiv1+2-1=2\bmod4. $

- If $n\equiv3\bmod4$,

then $7^{n+1}-(n+1)7^n-1\equiv(-1)^{n+1}-0-1\equiv 1-0-1=0\bmod4$.